# Python TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) - (OpenCV / Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, integer, tuples

I know that there have been many similar questions around, but none of those seem to work for my problem. That's why I decided to create another post.

To start off, the basic idea of the following code is that it will detect the pixel value of a specific coordinate in order to create a rectangle with the same color.

This is my code:

```
# open image
img = cv2.imread("image.png")

# set coordinates for rectangle
start_point = (35, 39) 
end_point = (50, 60)

# get pixel value of start point; outputs something like "[132 42 52]"
pixel = img[start_point].astype(int) 
R = pixel[0]
G = pixel[1]
B = pixel[2]

# outputs type: "<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.int32'> <class 'numpy.int32'> <class 'numpy.int32'>"
print(type(pixel), type(R), type(G), type(B))

# draws rectangle
color = (R, G, B)
image = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, color, -1)
```

Even though the values "R", "G" and "B" are converted into integers by using "astype(int)" I get the following error:

```
image = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, color, -1)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

By using numbers like 30, 53, 100 as the color values everything works out perfectly fine. There just seems to be a problem with the values I receive by setting the pixel value of a coordinate in this image. I don't really know where the problem could be, so I appreciate every help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is using `color = (int(R), int(G), int(B))`.

The issue is that even when using `pixel = img[start_point].astype(int)`, the elements of `pixel` are of type `<class 'numpy.int32'>` and not of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You answered yourself - you passed type `numpy.int32` and they expect `int`. For humans it's the same, but python has a hard time handling all types convertible to one another.
You have to help them by passing:

```
image = cv2.rectangle(img, start_point, end_point, [int(x) for x in color], -1)
```

Comment: Oh wow, my bad. Based on lack of knowledge I didn't even know that there's a difference between Int32 and a "normal" integer. Thank you very much! @NadavS